# How to interface a BQ76PL536EVM with a MSP430 uC using the sample code?

Tags: batteries, spi, msp430

I am trying to follow the application report : http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa478/slaa478.pdf to setup communication between a BQ76PL536-EVM (TI battery monitor) with a MSP430 uC board (I am using a MSP-TS430PN80USB with MSP430F5529 uC) and have made connections and setup as explained in the application report. I have further programmed the uC with the sample code provided (link for the code at the end of report) and am now trying USB communication of the uC board with a PC. The board should report battery voltages etc when I send 'p' across the serial connection. A serial connection is established but it doesnt show anythign that I type, not even the alphabets I am typing, and also doesnt show any response.

I have tested both boards individually and they work. I have tried USB communication examples on the uC board and they work too.

The battery monitor communicates over SPI and I have tried an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi too to talk to the battery monitor, but even that has not worked.

Any ideas on how I could debug the system further ?

Comment: If it's failing on only this code, then its likely the wrong code example, or a wiring error between the msp430 and the BQ.

Comment: It is not failing as in, its not giving an error, it is just not communicating. This is a 'proven' app report and a standard example that people before have used (I only had the code for MSP430 and BQ76, with other devices I tried on my own). Wiring can always be an issue, but I am doing it as it was laid, out, and so have to figure out a way to debug it.

Comment: Are you using the EVMs and have all of the proper jumper configurations as described in section 1.1?

Comment: Do you have some battery connected? Have you looked at the SPI with a logic analyzer?

Comment: @DigitalNinja: Yes I have done the Jumper connections as in the app report and I am using the EVMs.

Comment: @CL : I have a power supply in place of a battery, but that is a valid substitution, as is given in the BQ76PL536EVM user's guide (http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ug/sluu437d/sluu437d.pdf). I do not have an access to a Logic Analyzer, I will try to do that.